# th:field parameter syntax using Thymeleaf in Spring

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've always seen th:field used like this:

```
<form th:object="${bla}" method="POST">
   <div>
       <label for="bla"> </label>
       <input type="text" th:field="*{blabla}">
       <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </div>
</form>
```

but is it possible, in the case I had to search by 2 different fields, to do something like:

**th:field="{blabla, thebla}"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer : **No** it doesn't permit such a behavior AFAIK.
Check the [Official doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html)

A workaround: Your can always send one value with separators..